# Check whether variable exists in .each() array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, backbone.js, each

I have the following code which iterates through each item looking for it's `ID` attribute `existingId`. I also have a variable `courseId` which grabs the value that a user inputs in a text box, I am looking to throw an error message when a `courseId` matches an `existingId` but it does not seem to be working.

```
this.courseTemplates.each(function (template) {
            var existingId = [template.get('ID')];
            if ($.inArray(courseId.val(), existingId) > -1) {
                $.growl.error({
                    title: '',
                    message: "Course Id Already Exists",
                    location: 'tr',
                    duration: 3000,
                    size: 'large'
                });
            }
            return;
        });
```

The value of `existingId` does not output as one array but multiple. How can I go about achieving a check that `courseId` does not exist within any iteration of `existingId`? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

### Example JSON output of existingId

```
{"existingId":["TEST1"]}
{"existingId":["MetBats"]}
{"existingId":["TEST"]}
{"existingId":["TB060"]}
{"existingId":["OST027"]}
{"existingId":["CC035"]}
{"existingId":["GC078"]}
{"existingId":["DX022"]}
```

Preferably I'd like the output to be...

```
{"existingId":["TEST1", "MetBats", "TEST", "TB060", "OST027", "CC035", "GC078", "DX022"]}
```

Comment: If you can provide an example JSON then it would be more helpful to understand

Comment: @AmanRawat I have updated my question with an example JSON output

Comment: try with `var existingId = this.courseTemplates.map(function(template) { return template.get('ID'); });`

Comment: then you can have your code `if ($.inArray(courseId.val(), existingId) > -1) {...` outside the each function

Comment: @oliv37 This worked great, thank you!